# What value should be written to run the code correctly?

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

What value should be written to run the code correctly. I give any amount I do not see any output.

```
f(T, Y) :-Y is sqrt(abs(T)) + 5*T^3.

main :-
    read(As),
    length(As, N), reverse(As , Rs),
    ( foreach(Ai , Rs), for(I, N - 1, 0,  -1) do
        Bi is f(Ai),
            ( Bi > 400  ->  printf("%w TOO  LARGE\n", I)
                ;
                printf("%w %w\n", [I, Bi])
            )
    ).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program works fine.  Maybe you forgot to terminate your data input with a fullstop/period?

```
[eclipse 2]: main.                     % Invoke 'main' from the ECLiPSe prompt.
 [3,7,5,2].                            % Input the list, terminate with fullstop.
```

produces this output

```
3 41.4142135623731
2 TOO  LARGE
1 TOO  LARGE
0 136.732050807569

Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Remember that, if you use one of the primitives that read terms in Prolog syntax (read/1,2, read_term/1,2, etc), each term has to terminated with a fullstop (although ECLiPSe also accepts end-of-file).

By the way, instead of using read/1, you would normally just pass data as an argument.  If you change your code in this way, you can just invoke `main([3,7,5,2]).`